# Do blankets need tzitzis?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, sleep

Blankets have four corners. So, do they require tzitzis?

Answer (score 6):

In SHU"T SHOEL UMASHIV he answers that according to the MORDECHAI only when a garment is worn in a way of clothing (DERECH LIVISHA) is one obligated in Tzitzis.

The SHUT of the MARSHAM adds that Tzitzis are meant to surround one on four sides so you could see them when looking in every one of the 4 directions. A blanket does not have that, which might be the reason we do not put Tzitzis on our blankets.

The main reason quoted is that a covering which is made for use at night does need Tzitzs (Kesus Laylah) and a blanket's main time of use is during the night.

Comment: good answer, but why so many CAPS? ;)

Comment: Please de-jargonify.

Comment: What about for the Rambam who holds kesus laylah is chayav bayom?

Comment: "[A] covering which is made for use at night **does** need Tzitzs" -- is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

The *[Sefer Hachinuch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch)* - in passing - [brings up](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34302&st=&pgnum=250) a [discussion](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=30&daf=40&format=pdf) in the *[G'mara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menahot)* that concludes that they do. That is, if we assume 'blanket' and *sadin* to be equivalent.

Comment: Just out of interest you actually have tzitzis on your blankets?

Comment: I once saw someone with tzitzit on his blanket - but he was in a Chabad family whose practice was to wear tzitzit at night. I presume he didn't wear a talit katan, and relied on the blanket instead. Alternatively, he was a smart guy and he may have been subtly making a point about the halacha: the blanket is an archetypical 4-cornered garment, but you say it doesn't need tzitzit because it's reserved for sleeping. Then what about your talit katan, since the one you wear at night is also reserved for sleeping?

Comment: @JoeinAustralia The Shulchan Aruch Ha-Rav makes it clear that you must wear the your sleeping talit katan occasionally during the day, otherwise as a night only garment it wouldn't need tzitzis.

Answer (score 2):

I think I remember seeing the Hazon Ish being Matir MeIkar HaDin to not place Sisit on the blanket.

Answer (score 1):

Qiẓur Shulḥan 'Arukh - Yalqut Yosef ([Oraḥ Ḥayim 18:9](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01355_part_2.html#%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%99%D7%97B-B%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%9FB%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%98)) states (my translation):

> סדינים ושמיכות שיש בהם ארבע כנפות, אף שהאדם מתכסה בהם גם ביום, פטורים מציצית. ויש מי שכתב דנכון לחוש ולהחמיר בסדין של צמר, והמחמיר תבא עליו ברכה, אבל מעיקר הדין דעת מרן שגם בסדין של צמר פטור מציצית.
>
> Sheets and blankets which have four corners, despite that one covers oneself with them during the day, do not require ẓiẓit. And there is one who wrote that it is proper to be stringent regarding a woolen sheet, and blessing should come upon one who is stringent. But, **according to the letter of the law, the opinion of Maran [HaShulḥan 'Arukh] is that even a woolen sheet does not require ẓiẓit.**

The Mishnah Berurah ([Siman 17, S.Q. 8](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_1/0052_Siman_17_Seif_3b-Siman_18_Seif_3.pdf)) brings, among other opinions, that of the Magen Avraham to round one corner to fulfill all opinions.

Answer (score 0):

The Talmud (Menachoth, 40:1) says "Our Rabbis taught: A linen garment is, according to Beth Shammai, exempt from zizith; but Beth
Hillel declare it liable. The halachah is in accordance with Beth Hillel"

Comment: Hi Nissim. How does this answer the question, which wasn't referring to any specific material AFAICT.

Comment: The original term in the Talmud is 'Sadin' (סדין), which translates to bedsheet

Comment: So the Talmud was discussing an argument about bedsheets? Why did the translation not reflect that? What was the basis of the argument between Beth Shammai and Beth Hillel about bedsheets?

Comment: On the next page (40:2) Rabbi Zera says that bedsheet doesn't need tzitzis because the passuk says 'that ye may look upon it' (וראיתם אותו) and he deducts that this part comes to teach us that nightware are exempt from tzitzis

Comment: But you sure downvote fast around here...

Comment: I'm only downvoting because you are misreading the text. It's actually not relevant to this discussion. The Gemara there is speaking about any linen garment, and R Zeira exempts it lest you come to wear it with woolen blue threads at night when there is no positive obligation to wear Tzitit that can override the prohibition of wearing Shaatnez.