# Does a Snuggie need tzitzis?

Tags: halacha, tzitzis, sleep

Snuggie is a popular brand of [sleeved blanket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeved_blanket). A sleeved blanket is a four-cornered blanket with sleeves, similar to a backwards bathrobe. It can be made of anything blankets are made of.

The answer to [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1701/do-blankets-need-tzitzis) explains why a blanket does not normally need tzitzis. But the presence of sleeves raises some questions.

- Is the presence of sleeves enough to constitute wearing it in the manner of clothing (derech levisha)?
- Does the arrangement of the four corners not being on all four sides of the body still render it exempt even when sleeves are present?

(In a practical situation, CYLOR of course.)

Answer (score 3):

If it's made of synthetic material (and it probably is):

- R' Moshe Feinstein (Igrot Moshe vol 2 #1) rules that it does not require tzitzit.
- The Tzitz Eliezer (vol 7 #3) and R' Ben Tzion Abba Shaul (Ohr l'Tziyon vol 2 2:3) rule that it does (because of a safek d'oraita l'chumra), but that you don't make the beracha (because of safek berachot l'hakel).

Comment: If you are only using it at night then it would be Patur as well.

Also, if it is owned by a woman and simply borrowed for short duration, it would also be Patur.

Comment: @Reddit_Rabbi What does the woman have to do with it?

Answer (score 2):

If it has 4 corners, it needs tzitzis. A blanket would also need, if worn as a garment. However, based on the pictures, it looks like the Snuggie has two corners instead of four. So it won't need Tzitzis.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does have four. The top two are normally draped over the shoulders.